# COM object of type Class to type Application, error loading library

Tags: c#, excel, dll, com, regsvr32

So I'm not entirely sure how to go about asking this so I'll list my trouble shooting along with the error I'm getting.

For reference, my program only works with 32-bit versions of Excel. I mistakenly had 2016 64-bit installed so I removed and re-installed 32-bit Excel. That works fine and it *appears* that the registry is correct. Everything is listed as 1.9 (and win32) which points to 2016. I don't see any reference to a difference between 32/64 bit in the registry.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).</error

According to my error message it's looking like I have a couple of issues:

- Possible errors in the registry, but I only have 1.9 under TypeLib (00020813-0000-0000-c000-000000000046) and it's listed as win32. **Pretty sure this isn't it**
- My custom DLL isn't registered. **More likely, but maybe I'm missing another DLL**
- Tried the full DLL itself, but it gave me this error when I tried using regsvr32 (in SySWOW64).
  Does this mean I need a different DLL registered? Should it be listed in the DLL that I can see once it's decompiled?

> "The module "Cutsom.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

I used a decompiler to see that 000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 is referenced in several libraries of the build, especially the Application and _Application parts. Did Office 2016 also change how Boolean values are treated? Do I just need to swap the interop around?

What other resources could I use to learn more about these COM types and DLL libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: This error is not about your dll, but about Excel registration. The system cannot find the type library (tlb or .dll, etc.) corresponding to the interface with ID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' which belongs to Excel. Try an Excel repair, or make sure you have selected all the required options (programmability, etc.) in Excel setup.

Comment: I've used repair and tried reinstallation several times. This has not solved the issue.

Could this also be a security/permissions issue?

Edit - I'll still run through installation again with another set of eyes.

Comment: TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY is more a registration issue than a security issue. Check the type lib is there, for example here is the result from SDK tool "Oleview" on my machine: https://i.imgur.com/WltBDla.png you can use this tool too: https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to compile that ole/com viewer, but I did run through the registry and what I have essentially matches https://i.imgur.com/vOrmY3w.png and we went through and re-compiled the dll again to look for 32-bit exclusively in case it was catching there. No dice still.

Comment: No there's a release version on the site, or OleView is from Windows SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer . Also make sure about the 32b vs 64b issue for example in my image, I only show the 64b version. You can also use ProcMon tool from sysinternals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and filter by registry access (you can also filter by process).

Comment: What is *Cutsom.dll*? ComVisible .NET assembly? If so, it has to be registered with regasm.exe, not regsvr32.exe

Comment: I think I found out this issue! Indeed it does look like it was a registration issue. We had an account that was logged on, but disconnected. (One of the people troubleshooting with me). Turns out that user was saving settings when the installation was going on and vice versa. Lesson learned on that. 
The registry is still the same as far as I can tell, but I've moved on to being able to troubleshoot other things. Thanks @SimonMourier for keeping me at it. I appreciate it.

Steeeve it's just a custom dll we had written, but I will double check with the assembly as it might be an issue.

Comment: You should answer yourself with some good info then :-)